# sqlite selection help needed

Tags: sqlite, select

I have the following bill table

```
building      name      amount      payments     receiptno
1234          name a    123         0            0
1234          name a    12          10           39
1234          name a    125         125          40
1235          name a    133         10           41
1235          name b    125         125          50
1234          name c    100         90           0
```

I want to select rows that amount minus payments is greater than zero and display the max value of receiptno

so I want to select only the following from building 1234

```
         name a     39
         name c     0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your description into SQL results in this:

```
SELECT building,
       name,
       MAX(receiptno)
FROM BillTable
WHERE amount - payments > 0
GROUP BY building,
         name
```

Comment: From my limited experience with SQLite this can work (but not for MySQL). Are you sure about SQLite?

Comment: i use SELECT building,
       name,
       MAX(receiptno)
FROM BillTable 
WHERE amount - payments > 0 AND building = 1234
GROUP BY building,
         name but receiptno is undefined...

Comment: @CL. yes you're right, I overlooked the groupby fields in select statement as well. I will delete my verbose answer..